# How to assign a value dynamically for a group filter in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table on SSRS 2008 like:

```
         [QuarterCount]
GROUP    Volume
[Group]  [sum(Volume)]
```

QuarterCount is a syntax like: -Q, where  is 1 if the current month is January to March, 2 if the current month is April to July and so on.

The "Volume" column has a group, by QuarterCount, and this column group has a filter like:

[image]

So basically this column will show the info belonging to this quarter and the same quarter last year. This table is working well like that, but what I need to do is to make the values here dynamic. I mean, I should not enter the values manually, the report should understand it based on today's date. So I need something like that:

```
=YEAR(Now()) & "-Q" & IF(MONTH(Now())>0 and MONTH(Now()) <= 3 then "1")
                      IF(MONTH(Now())>3 and MONTH(Now()) <= 6 then "2")
                      IF(MONTH(Now())>6 and MONTH(Now()) <= 9 then "3")
                      IF(MONTH(Now())>9 and MONTH(Now()) <= 12 then "4")
```

I could not find the correct way to provide it. Any help I would really appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this expression:

```
=Split(YEAR(Now()) & "-Q" & 
Switch(MONTH(Now())<=3,1,
MONTH(Now())<=6,2,
MONTH(Now())<=9,3,
MONTH(Now())<=12,4
) & "," &
YEAR(Now())-1 & "-Q" & 
Switch(MONTH(Now())<=3,1,
MONTH(Now())<=6,2,
MONTH(Now())<=9,3,
MONTH(Now())<=12,4
),",")
```

Let me know if this helps.